# How do I check the AJAX request in Chrome

Tags: json, ajax, google-chrome

How do I check if an AJAX request has been made in Chrome and how it looks like (e.g. the body, header and so on). Though the browser, not with code.

Comment: through code or browser?

Comment: Through the browser, will edit the question to clarify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the steps

- Open developer console by pressing `CTRL + SHIFT + I` and go to `Network` tab.
- Click on `XHR` tab( uncheck all other tab to see only ajax) and select `URL` you want to check(left side).
- Then You can inspect `Header`, `Cookies`, `Response` etc from respective tab(right side)

Google chrome:
[image: chrome]

Firefox:
[image: firefox]

Answer (score 2):

open the developers tool:

On windows/Linux: `F12` or `Ctrl + Shift + I`

On Mac: `Cmd + Opt + I`

Navigate to the *Network* tab - where you can see all the network activity.
Then when you see the request - click on it, and there you can see the Headers, the request and the response.

[image]