# Trying to get data from textbox and inserting it into a database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that is to be used to input information and register an account. The information is entered on the website and when the button 'register' is pressed it is validated by an external JavaScript method and afterwards, a PHP method is called using ajax which should take the information from the text boxes and enter it into the database. I can't seem to get the PHP getting the information working.

```php
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost:8080', 'root', null, 'salmonhouse');
/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (name, surname, email, address, password)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

$name = $_POST['name'];
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$email= $_POST['email'];
$address= $_POST['Address'];
$pass= $_POST['Password'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $name, $surname, $email, $address, $pass);
$stmt->execute();

?>
```

HTML textboxes

```
<form class="quote">

    <div class = inliner>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class = inliner>
        <label>Surname</label>
        <input id="surname" type="text" placeholder="Surname">
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Email</label><br>
        <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address"><br>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Address</label><br>
        <input id="Address" type="email" placeholder="Home Address"><br>
    </div>


    <div class = inliner>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input id="Password" type="text" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class = inliner>
        <label>Verify Password</label>
        <input id="vPassword" type="text" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <br><button class="button_1" type="button" onclick="Validate()">Register</button>

</form>
```

Calling javascript file from html page

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
          var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
          var surname =document.getElementById("surname").value;
          var email =document.getElementById("email").value;
          var pass=document.getElementById("Password").value;
          var passV =document.getElementById("vPassword").value;
          var address=document.getElementById("Address").value;
      </script>
            <script type= "text/javascript" src="asset/js/my_javascript.js"></script>
```

Actual javascript file

```
/* eslint-env browser */
/*jslint devel: true */
/* eslint-disable */
function Validate(){
    name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    surname =document.getElementById("surname").value;
    email =document.getElementById("email").value;
    pass=document.getElementById("Password").value;
    passV =document.getElementById("vPassword").value;
    var error = "";

    document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("surname").style.borderColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("Password").style.borderColor = "white";
    document.getElementById("vPassword").style.borderColor = "white";



    var count= 0;
    if(name.length == 0){
        document.getElementById("name").style.borderColor = "red";
        count =1;
        error = error + "Name cannot be empty\n"

    }
    if(surname.length == 0 ){
        document.getElementById("surname").style.borderColor = "red";
        count =1;
        error = error + "Surname cannot be empty\n"
    }
    if(email.length == 0 ){
        document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor = "red";   
        count =1;
        error = error + "Email cannot be empty\n"
    }
    if(!(email.includes("@"))){
        document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor = "red";   
        count =1;
        error = error + "Email needs to contain an @ symbol\n"
    }
    if(!(email.includes("."))){
        document.getElementById("email").style.borderColor = "red";   
        count =1;
        error = error + "Email needs to comtain a .com or similar\n"
    }

    if(pass!==passV){
        document.getElementById("Password").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("vPassword").style.borderColor = "red";
        count =1;
        error = error + "Passwords do not match\n"

    }
    if(!(pass.match(/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%&*()])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%&*()]{8,}$/))){
        document.getElementById("Password").style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById("vPassword").style.borderColor = "red";
        count =1;
        error = error + "Password must be atleat 8 long and contain a LowerCase, UpperCase, Number and a symbol."
    }
    if(false){
        alert("Please correct the following errors highlighted in red\n"+error);
    }
    else{
        alert("Name: " + name + "\nSurname: "+ surname + "\nEmail: "+ email+"\nPassword: "+pass+"\n Succesful Registration");
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "asset/php/inserting.php";
        xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
}
/* eslint-enable */
```

This PHP file is a separate file with just this code. I have tested and if I manually set the variables instead of trying to retrieve them the data is successfully inserted into the database. So from my testing it is simply the retrieval not working. I also tried `$_REQUEST['name']`

This is the ajax/xmlhttprequest code.

```
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "asset/php/inserting.php";
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: `$name = $_POST0['name'];` can't be correct. Should be `$_POST` not `$_POST0`. What errors are you getting? Why not show the HTML?

Comment: Sorry That was a miss type. It is $name = $_POST['name'];

Comment: I don't see you sending any actual data with your call to send.

Comment: I am not sending any data. I would like the php to just get the information from the html boxes directly. I was insure of how to send the data. Is it not possible this way? Should I be sending it?

Comment: `PHP` can't read `HTML` form data directly. `HTML` form data is available at browser side and `PHP` executes at server side. Read `HTML` form data using `Javascript` and send `PHP` page using `AJAX` or just use an `HTML` form that posts data to the target PHP page. In your example, I do not see you are passing any data in the Ajax `POST` call.

Comment: The data is local to your browser *unless and until* the form is submitted. But it appears you are not submitting the form. Instead, you are using AJAX to submit the request to the server. So, the AJAX code must include the data. Am I correct in my assumption?

Comment: Yes, if php cant read the form directly then I will need to pass the data using ajax. I am just submitting the request. Could you please then show how the url should look when passing multiple variables?

Comment: Again, if you showed the HTML and any relevant JavaScript event handlers that your AJAX call is a part of, it would clarify matters,

Comment: I added the places I call the javascript and the entire javascript file.

Comment: You will find this easier if you investigate using the jQuery library.

Comment: Without jquery is not possible to pass the variables by adding them into the url. I saw its possible to do one but unsure of how to do many.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do this without jQuery. But the *fully* correct answer that can handle all possible input data using XMLHttpRequest, which has not yet appeared, requires a lot of careful coding. Compare the XMLHttpRequest version with the jQuery version. Saying that the whole world uses jQuery shouldn't be an argument. But I will say it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use the jQuery library rather than XMLHttpRequest. You will need to include in the `<head>` section of your HTML a `<script>` tag to load the jQuery library from some CDN (Content Delivery Network). Also add `id="f"` to your `<form>` tag. Then your Ajax call can be as simple as:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'asset/php/inserting.php',
    data: $('#f').serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
    success: function(msg)
    {
        alert(msg); // show response from the php script.
    }
});
```

Comment: Will I need to declare f in the javascript file as it is currently external?

Comment: Ok I combined what you said and Swati ```data: "name=" + name + "&surname=" + surname + "&email=" + email + "&Address=" + address + "&Password=" + pass,``` sends the variables and it is now working.

Comment: `<form>` => `<form id="f">`. No need to declare `f`.

Comment: @Tristan If you are *not* using my `$('#f').serialize()` code to serialize the form, then  you better use `data: "name=" + encodeURIComponent(name) + etc ..."` as I indicated in an earlier comment or you might one day encounter data this will *not* work. This is why your version is not an improvement (and imagine if the form had 100 input fields).

Answer (score 1):

You can attached the variable in `ajax` call,  which you need to get in your php page using `&` for separating variable and `=` for assigning value .i,e :

```
 //attaching values to pass
    var data = "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&surname=" + surname + "&Address=" + Address + "&Password=" + Password;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

      request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }


    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       //if success do something here 
  alert("save");
      }
    };

    var url = "asset/php/inserting.php";
    request.open("POST", url, true);
    //send data to php page
    request.send(data);
```

Comment: I would recommend passing each form element through a call to encodeURIComponent in case the values contain *problematic* characters. Also missing is an `onreadystatechange` handler.

Comment: I have now tried this. For some reason its just not working. I check that all the variables names are correct. The request is made but the php just is not getting the information into the variables.

Comment: Did you got any error ? Check your console , also check ajax request in [network tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136512/how-do-i-check-the-ajax-request-in-chrome)

Comment: `var data = "name + encodeURIComponent(name) + &email= .... etc. ";` because what happens if there is, for example, a '&' or '?' or some character that is not in the  ASCII character set in one of the form values?

Comment: I check the console and did not find error, thanks anyway though. It is now working with jquery.