# Why after the jquery ajax post my link goes to action page of the form?It is not staying at the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

```js
$('#btnSave').click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                var empInputId = $('#input_id').val();
                var empJenis = $('#jenis').val();
                var empJarak = $('#jarak').val();
               
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    // url  : "/InputPembangunan/save",
                    url  : $("#saveEmpForm").attr("action"),
                    dataType : "JSON",
                    data : {input_id:empInputId, jenis:empJenis, jarak:empJarak },
                    success: function(result){
                        $('#jenis').val("");
                        $('#jarak').val("");
                        $('#addEmpModal').modal('hide');
                        // alert('Successfully called');
                        alert(result);
                        // listEmployee();
                        
                    },
                    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
                        alert('Exception:' + errorMessage);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="addEmpModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
      <form id="saveEmpForm" method="post" action="{base_url('InputPembangunan/save')}">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Employee</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">                       
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Jenis</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <input type="text" name="jenis" id="jenis" class="form-control" required>
              <input type="hidden" id="input_id"  name="input_id" class="form-control " value="{$input_id}">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Jarak</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <input type="text" name="jarak" id="jarak" class="form-control" required> 
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The code successfully manage to save the data in table using the following code

In the controller

```
public function save(){
        $data=$this->inputs_model->saveEmp();
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
```

In the model

```
public function saveEmp(){
        $data = array(              
                'input_id'          => intval($this->input->post('input_id')), 
                'jenis'             => $this->input->post('jenis'), 
                'jarak'             => $this->input->post('jarak'), 
                // 'input_id'           => 1, 
                // 'jenis'          => 'Jenis', 
                // 'jarak'          => 1, 
                'created_at'        => date("Y-m-d h:i:sa"),
                'updated_at'        => date("Y-m-d h:i:sa")
            );
        $result=$this->db->insert('input_jenis_industri',$data);
        return $result;
    }
```

But after saving the data, the ajax call causes the website link to be redirected to http://localhost/esdr-dark/InputPembangunan/save , this the action of the form. It is submitting like usual post submission not like ajax posting.

Technically, it should just remain at the same link of the ajax call.

How to fix the error. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Is it making an actual AJAX request at all? Sounds like some JS error might prevent what you are trying to do there from happening altogether, and you are just seeing the result of a _normal_ form submission. (The parameter names you use in your AJAX request  are the same as the original form field names, so your server-side logic will probably create a new record, no matter if you actually send this data via AJAX, or normal form submission.)

Comment: Do you get the success `alert(result)` ?

Comment: No, i did not get the alert success message.

Comment: ....but the data is being saved on the `DB` - correct - can you check the network console to see what being returned as the error ?

Comment: AlwaysHelping how to check network console? what data i need to check. I am not getting any error from the ajax call. Thanks

Comment: [How do I check the AJAX request in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136512/how-do-i-check-the-ajax-request-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

The button is changing the page because its type is **submit**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">Save</button>
```

changing its type to **button** should fix it

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">Save</button>
```