# Python request.get() not working as intended

Tags: python, web-scraping, request

I'm trying to scrape some data from https://p2p.binance.com/en/trade/all-payments/USDT?fiat=AUD

```
!pip install bs4
from lxml import lxml 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://p2p.binance.com/en/trade/all-payments/USDT?fiat=AUD'
requests.get(url)
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html')
```

after that

`soup.find('div',attrs={'class' : 'css-1m1f8hn'})` shows nothing. This is just one of many items I'd like to scrape.

How can I fix that?

Comment: The page is like 99% Javascript and CSS. No wonder it does not find any `<div>`.

Comment: a = soup.find_all(class_="css-1m1f8hn")
print(a)

also shows nothing btw.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `find_all` with `class_` argument: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

Comment: a = soup.find_all(class_="css-1m1f8hn") print(a) also shows nothing.

Comment: Oh, maybe the you need to instantiate the parse as: `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = 'https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
payload = {"proMerchantAds":False,"page":1,"rows":10,"payTypes":[],"countries":[],"publisherType":None,"asset":"USDT","fiat":"AUD","tradeType":"BUY"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    res = s.post(link,json=payload)
    for item in res.json()['data']:
        print(item['adv']['price'])
```

Prints:

```
1.59
1.60
1.61
1.62
1.63
1.63
1.64
1.64
1.66
1.66
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much. I'll try to learn what each of the commands do.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you walk me through the code? I'm still a newbie.
How do you managed to get the link 'https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search' , which works and not the original site to scrape? That link is just blank?

Comment: Give [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44136683/9189799) a go for the clarity.

Comment: Got it! thanks. Can I trouble you with getting "Limit/Available" data from the same page? :')

Comment: Try creating another post to ask a new question.

Comment: Nevermind. I've got it. I replaced "price" with "tradableQuantity".

Answer (score 0):

It will be little difficult to scrap exactly this element because it loads by js after the page loads. It means that there will no target element in html page that you receive with get request.

You can check it out like that:

```py
url = 'https://p2p.binance.com/en/trade/all-payments/USDT?fiat=AUD'
response = requests.get(url)
open('test.html', 'wb').write(responce.content)
```

and then open html with browser to see raw page from server.

You can look for requests to internal binance api with browser devtools in network tab. Then there is a way to repeat this request from python code and retreive target data

upd: that's what robots.txt did in his answer